# Не могу поднять Laravel проект

Tags: laravel

Залил исходный код проекта в `/var/www/laravel/`, сделал миграции. Запускаю `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0` и сервер работает. Но нужно как-то связать его с nginx.

Файл /etc/nginx/sites-available⁩/default: (IP - IP адрес сервера)

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/laravel/public;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name IP;
charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Но сервер выдает пустую страницу
ps `nginx -t` выдает:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

В чем может быть проблема или мб есть инструкции по деплою laravel проекта (nginx/apache - не важно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте пару строк в конфиг:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /var/www/laravel/public;
    try_files      $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)\$;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо!  Странно, что в документации этих строчек не было